# What's the difference to use past simple and past perfect tense when we use subjunctive mood in the past tense?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, subjunctives

I'm reading Harry Potter. I found a difference in chapter 6 between the American version and the British version

British Version:

> Half terrified, half furious, they acted as though any chair with Harry in it **was** empty.

American version:

> Half terrified, half furious, they acted as though any chair with Harry in it **were** empty.

Ｉ have three questions:

1. What the difference between **was** and **were**?
2. Do they both use **subjunctive**?
3. If they use **subjunctive**, why don't they use past perfect tense, given that the thing happened in the past. That's:

> Half terrified, half furious, they acted as though any chair with Harry in it had been empty.

My grammar book gives an example:

> If the landslide had occurred a few seconds later, the bus could have passed through safely.

Here's another example in Grammar in Use (unit 118):

> When I told them my plan, they looked at me as though I was mad.

May I write?

> When I told them my plan, they looked at me as though I had been mad.

Here is Harry Potter context:

> Harry’s last month with the Dursleys wasn’t fun. True, Dudley was now so scared of Harry he wouldn’t stay in the same room, while Aunt Petunia and Uncle Vernon didn’t shut Harry in his cupboard, force him to do anything, or shout at him — in fact, they didn’t speak to him at all. **Half terrified, half furious, they acted as though any chair with Harry in it were
> empty.** Although this was an improvement in many ways, it did become a bit depressing after a while.

Comment: Harry Potter...there are at least seven books. Can you please give us the title?

Comment: The first one: Harry Potter And The Sorcerer's Stone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of the "subjunctive" *were* after *as though* is variable in modern use: in this case, I prefer the original "was" to the American editor's "were", but both are possible. (I think my preference is because it is not a true counterfactual: in "they acted as if the chair was/were empty", there is not actually a counterfactual world proposed in which the chair was empty - they are simply choosing to pretend that. I'm not entirely sure why I prefer it though).

As for the past perfect: we use a past perfect *when we are looking back from a later time in the past* and not otherwise. There is no such circumstance here.

In your example from the grammar book, "the bus could have passed" is not a past perfect: it's the so-called "perfect infinitive" (better, "past infinitive") used with the modal "could" - so effectively it is the past - not the past perfect - of "could pass".

In your second example, *they looked at me as if I had been mad* is perfectly grammatical, but means "as if I had been mad at some earlier time". It doesn't mean "as if I was mad at the time when they looked at me".

Comment: And the Dursleys acted as though Harry's chair _was empty_ at the time, not _had been empty_ earlier.

Comment: I think it's truly *appalling* that American publishers take it upon themselves to "bowlderize / regularize" (whichever suits your perspective) perfectly good English like that. If I can put up with my spellchecker insisting on ***-ize*** in this comment, Americans should be able to deal with more modern phrasing. It's like they're locked down against any further linguistic change since Webster!

Comment: Careful, @FumbleFingers, your jingoism is showing.

Comment: Yeah, FF is right. Those stupid American editors And I am calling them that and I am American. I wish people would stop using that term subjunctive.

Comment: ColinFine: *If I'd have known that Americans still think my **'d** there stands for **would**, I'd never have bothered to read any books by US authors!* Seriously, until I started using ELU, I had no idea that anyone apart from non-Anglophone Germans and French would expand it to *If I **would have** known...* rather than *If I **had have** known.* (But what do I know! :)

Comment: My grammar book said: If the time of the sentence is in the past, and the verb uses the past to express the hypothetical mood of "non-fact", then "past past" is "past perfect", so the hypothetical mood of the past time should be expressed by "past to perfect". But now I think we are also able to use "past" to express "past hypothesis".

Comment: @Lambie: I enthusiastically agree. "Subjunctive" is a term used for a particular family of synthetic verb forms in a number of European languages. It is (almost) obsolete in English - "were" is the only surviving distinct subjunctive form - and the habit of using the word to mean "a construction which, if I wanted to translate it into certain other languages, I would use a subjunctive verb form for it" is obfuscatory and unhelpful. (Just like "future", but that's another story).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I find _If I had have known_ malformed and completely ungrammatical, so _If I'd have known_ must be expanded to _If I would have known_. That is not in my dialect, but it is at least syntactically analysable.

Comment: It's nice to know you at least think it's "syntactically analysable" (I'm not sure much-lamented John Lawler could have brought himself to go that far! :) I think my unpacking to [*If I **had** have known...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+I+had+have+known&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) may be partly because I'd rarely if ever heard the uncontracted version until I spent a year living on the Continent. Then I was repeatedly exposed to French and German students practicing their English on me - and I thought *they* were the "illiterate" ones!

Comment: Well, _I would have known_ is normal in the apodosis, just not in the protasis. I don't find _I had have known_ normal - or even grammatical - anywhere.